# Grails i18n error message for range - grails-localizations plugin

Tags: grails

I am currently getting the following error message in a GSP page:

> Property [namespace] of class [class com.domain.Tld] with value
>   [partnerFebruary10BTESTTEST] does not fall within the valid size range
>   from [0] to [20]

I would like to replace it with my own custom message.

I have added tried the following to `messages.properties`:

```
com.domain.Tld.namespace.size.error.com.domain.Tld.namespace=The provided domain is too large and must not exceed {4} characters.
```

and

```
com.domain.Tld.namespace.size.toobig=The provided domain is too large and must not exceed {4} characters.
```

I have seen the other posts such as [Grails Problem with custom error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250667/grails-problem-with-custom-error-messages) but I wasn't able to solve my problem.

### Update

Domain constraints are:

```
static constraints = {
    namespace size: 0..20, nullable: true, unique: "name"
}
```

I also found a class called `Localization.groovy` with a method `static String decodeMessage(String code, Locale locale)`. In the debugger the code `default.invalid.size.message` is being used when this method is called.

### Update2

I figured out that the specific project is using the localization plugin (https://github.com/halfbaked/grails-localizations) that basically loads the properties files into the databases. When a lookup for a code is made, the `decodeMessage` method is called. The implementation of the specific `decodeMessage` method was causing the nulls due to the implementation and hence the messages were never found.

Comment: Can you put your domain constraints here??

Comment: just try  `tld.namespace.size.toobig=your mesage` domain name should be in small

Comment: Actually I think I know what the issue is. Their using custom code to lookup the messages through a class called `LocalizationMessageSource extends AbstractMessageSource implements ResourceLoaderAware`. I managed to get it to work but the custom code was the issue.